# Reading from my MIPS array

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am trying to write a short program in MIPS, just for personal development and the goal is to prompt the user for 10 integer values, store them into an array and then print all 10 of the values on their own lines. I am able to write all of the integers the user inputs into the array properly, however I am not able to get the code to read from the array properly.

I will enter the integer values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. When it prints the values, it will print 10 and then print 0 a total of 9 times.

Thank you for the help

```
.data
    array: .space 40
    prompt: .asciiz "Please enter a value: "
    space: .asciiz "\n"

.text
    addi $t0, $zero, 0 #Writting Array Location
    addi $t3, $zero, 0 #Printing Array Location
    la $s0, array

    loop:
        #Prompt user for a value
        la $v0, 4
        la $a0, prompt
        syscall

        #Store the value into T1
        add $v0, $zero, 5
        syscall
        add $t1, $v0, $zero

        #Store the contents of T1 into the array
        sll $t2, $t0, 2
        add $t2, $t2, $s0
        sw $t1, ($s0)

        beq $t0, 9, endLoop #After 10 entries, we want to export the list
        addi $t0, $t0, 1 #If it's not at 10 entries, we want to loop this section
    j loop

    endLoop:
        #Resetting the counters
        addi $t0, $zero, 0
        addi $t2, $zero, 0

        j printArray

    printArray:
        #Read the value from the array
        sll $t2, $t0, 2
        add $t2, $t2, $s0
        lw $t1, ($t2)

        #print the value found
        la $v0, 1
        la $a0, ($t1)
        syscall

        #Add a newline
        la $v0, 4
        la $a0, space
        syscall


        beq $t0, 9, quitProgram #After 10 entries, we will quit program
        addi $t0, $t0, 1 #If it's not at 10 entries, we want to loop this section
    j printArray

    quitProgram:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall`
```

Comment: `sw $t1, ($s0)` is wrong, you store all elements into the first item. You meant `sw $t1, ($t2)`. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for the help. What would you recommend using in the future?

Comment: Both the mars and spim/qtspim simulators have builtin assembler and debugger. Personally, I use mars See: http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/index.htm

Comment: Please post how you solved your problem as an answer if you don't mind.